# Is a smooth ring extension of a UFD a UFD?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $A \subseteq B$ be noetherian integral domains, $A$ a UFD, and $B$ a smooth $A$-algebra (=the definition of a smooth algebra can be found in
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207595/when-a-smooth-algebra-is-regular).

Is $B$ a UFD too?

Actually, I have a specific example in mind where $B$ is normal (=integrally closed), but I wish to know if $B$ is a UFD.

Also, in my specific example, the fraction field of $A$ is NOT assumed to equal the fraction field of $B$, so I prefer an answer not assuming this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no".
Indeed $A=\mathbb R[X]$ is a PID, and hence a UFD.    However if you take $$B=\mathbb R[X,Y,Z]/\langle Y^2+Z^2-1\rangle$$ you obtain a smooth $A$-algebra which is not a UFD and this example satisfies all your requirements: $A$ and $B$ are noetherian normal domains with different fraction fields.

**Edit**
At the OP's request here is an example with $\mathbb C$ as the base field:
Take $A=\mathbb C[X]$ and $B=\mathbb C[X,Y,Z,T]/\langle Y^2+Z^2+T^2-1\rangle$.
Again  $A,B$ are noetherian, normal integral domains and $B$ is a smooth  $A$-algebra, and yet $B$ is not a UFD.

Note carefully that the obvious candidate $B'=\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/\langle Y^2+Z^2-1\rangle$  for answering  the OP's new request for an example over $\mathbb C$ doesn't work because $B'$ **is** factorial.

Comment: Very nice! (I suspected that there exists a counterexample to my question, though could not find one). Can you "generalize" your counterexample to the case where $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$? (then $B$ should be a quotient of a polynomial ring in four indeterminates)?

Comment: No, my example does not generalize to the base field $\mathbb C$. The root of the problem is that $\mathbb C[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-1\rangle $ **IS** a UFD while $\mathbb R[X,Y]/\langle X^2+Y^2-1\rangle $ was not a UFD.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Does anyone have a counterexample over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I have given such an example in an Edit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no" even if $B$ is étale over $A$.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of positive genus over $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $f \colon X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a nonconstant morphism.  Fix a nonempty open subvariety $U \subsetneq \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $f^{-1} U \to U$  is étale.  Write $U = \operatorname{Spec} A$ and $f^{-1} U = \operatorname{Spec} B$.  Then $A$ and $B$ are Dedekind domains, and the class group $\operatorname{Pic}(A)$ is a quotient of $\operatorname{Pic} (\mathbb{C}[x]) = 0$, but $\operatorname{Pic}(B)$ is a quotient of the uncountable group $\operatorname{Pic}(X)$ by a finitely generated subgroup, hence uncountable.

Comment: Another example, showing that the answer is "no" even for an étale extension of local rings: The ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is a UFD (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607041/is-mathbbrx-y-z-x2y2z2-a-ufd ) but $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ is not (cf. Hartshorne, Algebraic geometry, II.6.5.2), and this remains true after localizing both at the origin.

Comment: The previous comment is closely related to Georges Elencwajg's comment of May 26, 2015 at 17:05.